# Error when use JDL in Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, mariadb, liquibase, jhipster

I have a problem when use JDL in Jhipster. I design my entities with JDL-Studio, this is jhipster-jdl.jh file after created:

```
    entity Member {
        fullName String required maxlength(100),
        birthDay LocalDate,
        address String maxlength(100),
        phone String maxlength(12),
        avatar String maxlength(100),
        aboutMe String maxlength(5000),
        systemStatus SystemStatus required,
        star Integer required
    }

    entity RealEstate {
        useFor UseFor required,
        location String maxlength(100),
        address String required maxlength(100),
        acreage Float required,
        price Float required, 
        currencyUnit CurrencyUnit required,
        typeRent TypeRent,
        status Status required,
        systemStatus SystemStatus required,
        description String maxlength(7000),
        star Integer required,
        numberBedRooms Integer,
        numberBathRooms Integer,
        avatar String maxlength(100)
        buildIn LocalDate,
        numberViews Integer required,
        createDate ZonedDateTime required
    }

    entity TypeRealEstate {
        name String required maxlength(50),
        number Integer required
    }

    entity Project {
        name String required maxlength(100),
        address String maxlength(100),
        location String maxlength(100),
        avatar String maxlength(100),
        price Float,
        description String maxlength(10000)
        tag String maxlength(200)
    }

    entity TypeProject {
        name String required maxlength(50)
        number String required
    }

    entity Coordinate {
        lat Float required,
        lnt Float required,
        type TypeCoordinate required
    }

    entity Bounds {

    }

    entity Question {
        content String required maxlength(1000)
        timeQuestion ZonedDateTime required,
        answer String required maxlength(1000),
        timeAnswer ZonedDateTime required,
        levelOfSatisfaction Float min(0) max(5)
    }

    entity Tag {
        name String required maxlength(50),
        number Integer required
    }


    entity Notification {
        content String required maxlength(100),
        typeNoti TypeNoti required
    }

    enum UseFor {
        SALE, RENT
    }

    enum CurrencyUnit {
        MILLION, BILLION
    }

    enum TypeRent {
        MONTH, YEAR
    }

    enum Status {
        AVAILABLE, NOT_AVAILABLE
    }

    enum SystemStatus {
        PENDING, APPROVED, NOT_APPROVE, LOCKED
    }

    enum TypeCoordinate {
        REAL_ESTATE, PROJECT, BOUNDS
    }

    enum TypeNoti {
        ANSWER, QUESTION, STAR
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Member{user} to User
    }


    relationship OneToMany {
        Member{realEstate} to RealEstate{poster}
    }

    relationship OneToMany {
        Project{realEstate} to RealEstate{project}
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Coordinate{project} to Project{coordinate}
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Coordinate{realEstate} to RealEstate{coordinate} 
    }

    relationship ManyToMany {
        Member{userStar} to User
    }

    relationship OneToMany {
        RealEstate{question} to Question
    }

    relationship OneToMany {
        Project{question} to Question
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Question{user} to User
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Bounds{southWest} to Coordinate
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Bounds{northEast} to Coordinate
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        RealEstate{bounds} to Bounds
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Project{bounds} to Bounds
    }

    relationship ManyToOne {
        Notification{user} to User  
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Notification{question} to Question
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Notification{realEstate} to RealEstate
    }

    relationship OneToOne {
        Notification{project} to Project
    }

    relationship ManyToMany {
        RealEstate{userStar} to User
    }

    relationship ManyToMany {
        RealEstate{tag} to Tag{realEstate}  
    }

    relationship ManyToMany {
        Project{tag} to Tag{project}
    }

    relationship OneToMany {
        TypeRealEstate{realEstate} to RealEstate{type}
    }

    relationship OneToMany {
        TypeProject{project} to Project{type}
    }

    paginate RealEstate, Member, Project, Question, Notification with infinite-scroll

    dto * with mapstruct
```

And then I use command yo `jhipster:import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh` to generator the entities and it run success, nothing error. But when I run my project with command `./mvnw` then my project can't run, this is log:

```
2016-10-27 09:18:31.099 ERROR 8835 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:17: unexpected token: member
2016-10-27 09:18:31.103 ERROR 8835 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:17: unexpected token: member

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: member
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1343)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1062)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 53 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.009 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-27T09:18:32+07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 65M/527M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using Mariadb. I don't know what going on, please help me! Thank everyone

Comment: Replace "required" with "NOT NULL", "String maxlength" with "VARCHAR", and a few other cosmetic things.  Then jetison jdl, which seems to be getting in the way.  I see nothing that looks like `INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY`, so I suspect you will be in trouble later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run Maven test you can see this :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: member near line 1, column 17 [select distinct member from com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Member member left join fetch member.userStars]
```

This is because Member is a reserved word in JPQL (the MEMBER OF expression).

Just change the name of the Member entity and it should work.