# Error using ManyToMany relation with JDL - JHipster

Tags: spring, reactjs, hibernate, many-to-many, jhipster

I would like to have a Member entity containing an array of Allergy entities, so I created 2 entities with a ManyToMany relationship, but the maven build is failing. When I use the below JDL model, I get back an error from hibernate, telling me the validation fails for query *findOneWithEagerRelationships(Long)*.
I use React frontend.

The JDL model:
[JDL model of array Allergy in Member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iohJx.png)

JDL raw:

```
entity Member {
    name String required,
    birthday LocalDate,
    phone String,
    address String,
    postcode String,
    city String,
    diet Diet,
}

enum Diet {
    NONE, VEGETARIAN, VEGAN
}

entity Allergy {
    type String required
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Member{allergy(type)} to Allergy
}
```

Why, with this simple model, does the build fail? 
Yes I also tried

```
relationship ManyToMany {
    Member{allergy(type)} to Allergy{member}
}
```

Been debugging for 4 hours straight now.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for
>   method public abstract java.util.Optional
>   nl.cognicode.jcagenda.repository.MemberRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(java.lang.Long)!

Stack trace:

```
...
2018-10-04 01:53:39.526  INFO 5700 --- [  restartedMain] n.c.jcagenda.config.WebConfigurer        : Web application fully configured
2018-10-04 01:53:39.877 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] n.c.jcagenda.security.jwt.TokenProvider  : Using a Base64-encoded JWT secret key
2018-10-04 01:53:41.591 ERROR 5700 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:8: unexpected token: member
2018-10-04 01:53:41.602 ERROR 5700 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:8: unexpected token: member

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: member
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1263)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1040)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:748)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:319)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:198)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:565)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:558)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:560)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550)
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
        at nl.cognicode.jcagenda.JcagendaApp.main(JcagendaApp.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

2018-10-04 01:53:41.606 ERROR 5700 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:56: unexpected token: member
2018-10-04 01:53:41.607 ERROR 5700 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:56: unexpected token: member

[...]

2018-10-04 01:53:41.613 ERROR 5700 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:79: unexpected token: member
2018-10-04 01:53:41.638 ERROR 5700 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:79: unexpected token: member

[...]

2018-10-04 01:53:41.687  WARN 5700 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberResource' defined in file [C:\Users\peter\Code\jcagenda\target\classes\nl\cognicode\jcagenda\web\rest\MemberResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional nl.cognicode.jcagenda.repository.MemberRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(java.lang.Long)!
2018-10-04 01:53:41.702 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.jcagenda.domain.Member         : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.703 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.jcagenda.domain.Allergy        : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.708 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.cognicode.jcagenda.domain.User   : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.713 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.jcagenda.domain.Authority      : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.726 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.j.domain.Allergy.members       : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.743 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.j.domain.User.authorities      : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.747 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.c.j.domain.Member.allergies      : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.762 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.773 DEBUG 5700 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Close successful.
2018-10-04 01:53:41.833 ERROR 5700 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberResource' defined in file [C:\Users\peter\Code\jcagenda\target\classes\nl\cognicode\jcagenda\web\rest\MemberResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional nl.cognicode.jcagenda.repository.MemberRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(java.lang.Long)!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
        at nl.cognicode.jcagenda.JcagendaApp.main(JcagendaApp.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional nl.cognicode.jcagenda.repository.MemberRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(java.lang.Long)!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional nl.cognicode.jcagenda.repository.MemberRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(java.lang.Long)!
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:565)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:558)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:560)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550)
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: member near line 1, column 8 [select member from nl.cognicode.jcagenda.domain.Member member left join fetch member.allergies where member.id =:id]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy165.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
        ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: member near line 1, column 8 [select member from nl.cognicode.jcagenda.domain.Member member left join fetch member.allergies where member.id =:id]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
        ... 70 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-04T01:53:42+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn.. Member is a reserved word...

> This is because Member is a reserved word in JPQL (the MEMBER OF
>   expression).
>
> Just change the name of the Member entity and it should work.

also see [Error when use JDL in Jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275667/error-when-use-jdl-in-jhipster)

Comment: You should report the issue on github https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster because so far MEMBER is a reserved keyword for Oracle DB only, see https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-core/search?q=member&unscoped_q=member